# Kibana behind Nginx reverse proxy - URL resource appending

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, reverse, kibana

I have a trouble with accessing Kibana over the reverse proxy on Nginx.

Nginx configuration:

```
location /development/kibana {
                proxy_pass https://kibana.server.com/;
        }
```

So when I am accessing the reverse proxy by http://my.proxy.com/development/kibana

My URL is rewrited to http://my.proxy.com/app/kibana

Which occurrs in 404 error, as there is nothing like '/app/kibana' on the reverse proxy.

What is the best way to fix that rewriting URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, by removing trailing slash from end of the proxy pass directive:

```
proxy_pass https://kibana.server.com;
```